# SQLAlchemy, PostgreSQL Connection Pooling

Tags: python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, postgresql-9.4

Hopefully this should be a quick answer for somebody.  I've looked through the docs a bit, but still haven't found a definitive answer.  I have a number of 'idle' connections that stick around, even if I perform a session.close() in SQLAlchemy.  Are these idle connections the way SQLAlchemy/Postgres handle connection pooling?

This is the query I used to check db connection activity

`SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity ;`

Here is sample code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

application = Flask(__name__)
application.config.from_object('config')
db = SQLAlchemy(application)


class Brand(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

@application.route('/')
def documentation():
    all = Brand.query.all()
    db.session.remove() #don't need this since it's called on teardown
    return str(len(all))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Closing a session does not immediately close the underlying DBAPI connection. The connection gets put back into the pool for subsequent reuse.

From the [SQLAlchemy docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_transaction.html#managing-transactions):

> [...] For each [`Engine`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Engine) encountered, a [`Connection`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection) is associated with it, which is acquired via the [`Engine.contextual_connect()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Engine.contextual_connect) method. [...]

Then, [`Engine.contextual_connect()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Engine.contextual_connect) points you to [`Engine.connect()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Engine.connect), which states the following:

> The [`Connection`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection) object is a facade that uses a DBAPI connection internally in order to communicate with the database. This connection is procured from the connection-holding [`Pool`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html#sqlalchemy.pool.Pool) referenced by this Engine. When the [`close()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection.close) method of the [`Connection`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection) object is called, the underlying DBAPI connection is then returned to the connection pool, where it may be used again in a subsequent call to [`connect()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Engine.connect).

Comment: Do you have a link to documentation that describes this?  This leaves some interpretation: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/pooling.html

Comment: @Trent [This](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_transaction.html#managing-transactions) describes how a session operates in relation to a connection. It tells you that a session acquires a connection through `Engine.contextual_connect` and ultimately [`Engine.connect`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Engine.connect), which then describes the pooling behavior.

Comment: I'm keenly interested in tying connection pooling back to the db.  That is, does the specific 'idle' state on the connection indicate that this could be part of that pooling?  My primary aim is to determine when/if we have a connection leak.